# how to use attachMediaStream?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I tried to test an exercise with WebRTC socket.io for a video call and chat .
I could not get the console errors on firefox but not attacking me the two local / remote stream between them .
my browser code is this

```js
'use strict';
var p = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ({video: true, audio: true});
// Clean-up function:
// collect garbage before unloading browser's window
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
hangup();
}
// Data channel information
var sendChannel, receiveChannel;
var sendButton = document.getElementById("sendButton");
var sendTextarea = document.getElementById("dataChannelSend");
var receiveTextarea = document.getElementById("dataChannelReceive");
// HTML5 <video> elements
var localVideo = document.querySelector('#localVideo');
var remoteVideo = document.querySelector('#remoteVideo');
// Handler associated with Send button
sendButton.onclick = sendData;
// Flags...
var isChannelReady = false;
var isInitiator = false;
var isStarted = false;
// WebRTC data structures
// Streams
var SStream;
var BStream;
var localStream;
var remoteStream;
// PeerConnection
var pc;
var pc_constraints = {
'optional': [
{'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': true}
]};
var sdpConstraints = {};
// Let's get started: prompt user for input (room name)
var room = prompt('Enter room name:');
// Connect to signaling server
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8181");
// Send 'Create or join' message to singnaling server
if (room !== '') {
console.log('Create or join room ', room);
socket.emit('create or join',room);
}


// Server-mediated message exchanging...
// 1. Server-->Client...
// this peer is the initiator

socket.on('created', function (room){
console.log('Created room ' + room);
isInitiator = true;
// Call getUserMedia()
    p.then (function (MediaStream) {
    SStream=MediaStream;
    localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL (MediaStream);
    localVideo.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
    console.log("add local stream");
    sendMessage('got user media');
    };
    });
    p.catch (function (err) {console.log (err.name);});
   checkAndStart();
   });
   
// Handle 'join' message coming back from server:
// another peer is joining the channel
   socket.on('join',function(room){
   console.log('this peer is the iniator of room '+room+' !');
   isChannelReady=true;
   })

// Handle 'joined' message coming back from server:
// this is the second peer joining the channel
   socket.on('joined', function (room){
   console.log('This peer has joined room ' + room);
   isChannelReady = true;
  // Call getUserMedia()
   p.then (function (MediaStream) {
   isChannelReady = true;
   BStream=MediaStream;
   remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL (MediaStream);
   remoteVideo.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
   console.log("add remote stream");
   sendMessage('got user media');
   };
   });
   p.catch (function (err) {console.log (err.name);});
   });

   
   
// Server-sent log message...
   socket.on('log', function (array){
   console.log.apply(console, array);
   });
// Receive message from the other peer via the signaling server
socket.on('message', function (message){
console.log('Received message: ', message);
 if (message === 'got user media') {
  console.log('sono in if');
  checkAndStart();
 } 
  else if (message.type === 'offer') {
    if (!isInitiator && !isStarted) {
     checkAndStart();
    }
   pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
   doAnswer();
   }   
    else if (message.type === 'answer' && isStarted) {
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
    } 
     else if (message.type === 'candidate' && isStarted) {
     var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({sdpMLineIndex:message.label,candidate:message.candidate});
     pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
     }
      else if (message === 'bye' && isStarted) {
      handleRemoteHangup();
      } 
});



// 2. Client-->Server
// Send message to the other peer via the signaling server
function sendMessage(message){
console.log('Sending message: ', message);
socket.emit('message', message);
}
// Channel negotiation trigger function
function checkAndStart() {
if (!isStarted && isChannelReady) {
 createPeerConnection();
isStarted = true;
if (isInitiator) {
doCall();
}
}
}
// PeerConnection management...
function createPeerConnection() {
try {
/*posso aggiungere turn, google ecc...*/
 pc = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [{ urls: 'stun:93.33.165.245' }] }, {
 'optional': [
 {'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': true}
 ]});

 if(isInitiator){
  SStream.getTracks().forEach(track => pc.addTrack(track,SStream));
  pc.ontrack= handleRemoteStreamAdded;}
 else{
  BStream.getTracks().forEach(track => pc.addTrack(track,BStream));}
 pc.onicecandidate = handleIceCandidate;
 console.log('create RTCPeerConnection');
 } 
catch (e) {
 console.log('Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: ' + e.message);
 alert('Cannot create RTCPeerConnection object.');
return;
}
pc.ontrack= handleRemoteStreamAdded;
pc.onremovestream = handleRemoteStreamRemoved;
if (isInitiator) {
try {
// Create a reliable data channel
sendChannel = pc.createDataChannel("sendDataChannel",
{reliable: true});
console.log('Created send data channel');
} catch (e) {
alert('Failed to create data channel. ');
console.log('createDataChannel() failed with exception: ' + e.message);
}
sendChannel.onopen = handleSendChannelStateChange;
sendChannel.onmessage = handleMessage;
sendChannel.onclose = handleSendChannelStateChange;
} else { // Joiner
pc.ondatachannel = gotReceiveChannel;
}
}
// Data channel management
function sendData() {
var data = sendTextarea.value;
if(isInitiator) sendChannel.send(data);
else receiveChannel.send(data);
console.log('Sent data: ' + data);
}
// Handlers...
function gotReceiveChannel(event) {
console.log('Receive Channel Callback');
receiveChannel = event.channel;
receiveChannel.onmessage = handleMessage;
receiveChannel.onopen = handleReceiveChannelStateChange;
receiveChannel.onclose = handleReceiveChannelStateChange;
}
function handleMessage(event) {
console.log('Received message: ' + event.data);
receiveTextarea.value += event.data + '\n';
}
function handleSendChannelStateChange() {
var readyState = sendChannel.readyState;
console.log('Send channel state is: ' + readyState);
// If channel ready, enable user's input
if (readyState == "open") {
dataChannelSend.disabled = false;
dataChannelSend.focus();
dataChannelSend.placeholder = "";
sendButton.disabled = false;
} else {
dataChannelSend.disabled = true;
sendButton.disabled = true;
}
}
function handleReceiveChannelStateChange() {
var readyState = receiveChannel.readyState;
console.log('Receive channel state is: ' + readyState);
// If channel ready, enable user's input
if (readyState == "open") {
dataChannelSend.disabled = false;
dataChannelSend.focus();
dataChannelSend.placeholder = "";
sendButton.disabled = false;
} else {
dataChannelSend.disabled = true;
sendButton.disabled = true;
}
}



// ICE candidates management
function handleIceCandidate(event) {
console.log('handleIceCandidate event: ', event);
if (event.candidate) {
sendMessage({
type: 'candidate',
label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
candidate: event.candidate.candidate});
} else {
console.log('End of candidates.');
}
}
// Create Offer
function doCall() {
console.log('Creating Offer...');
pc.createOffer(setLocalAndSendMessage, onSignalingError, sdpConstraints);
}
// Signaling error handler
function onSignalingError(error) {
console.log('Failed to create signaling message : ' + error.name);
}
// Create Answer
function doAnswer() {
console.log('Sending answer to peer.');
pc.createAnswer(setLocalAndSendMessage, onSignalingError, sdpConstraints);
}
// Success handler for both createOffer()
// and createAnswer()
function setLocalAndSendMessage(sessionDescription) {
pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
sendMessage(sessionDescription);
}
// Remote stream handlers...
function handleRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
attachMediaStream(BStream, event.stream);
BStream = event.stream;
}
function handleRemoteStreamRemoved(event) {
console.log('Remote stream removed. Event: ', event);
}
// Clean-up functions...
function hangup() {
console.log('Hanging up.');
stop();
sendMessage('bye');
}
function handleRemoteHangup() {
console.log('Session terminated.');
stop();
isInitiator = false;
}
function stop() {
isStarted = false;
if (sendChannel) sendChannel.close();
if (receiveChannel) receiveChannel.close();
if (pc) pc.close();
pc = null;
sendButton.disabled=true;
}
```

someone tell me where I'm wrong and how to fix ?

Answer (score 6):

`attachMediaStream` is not part of WebRTC. It's a shim [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) used to expose for setting `video.src` or `video.srcObject` (which Chrome still doesn't support, but Canary does).

In any case, you're passing in the wrong arguments, which should be an element and a stream, not two streams. I.e. make it:

```
attachMediaStream(remoteVideo, event.streams[0]);
```

or better, use the spec-way that adapter.js now supports on all browsers:

```
remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
```

**Important:** The `pc.ontrack` event contains `event.streams` (plural), not `event.stream`! - It's an array since a track may (but rarely does) exist in more than one stream.

If you're ***not*** using the latest *adapter.js*, then note that [`pc.ontrack`](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-rtcpeerconnection-ontrack) is only natively available in Firefox at the moment, so in Chrome you would need the older `pc.onaddstream` (and its `event.stream`).

**PS:** You're currently setting `remoteVideo.src` to the local video. Don't do that.

**PPS:** Remove `pc_constraints`. Really old stuff that will break Chrome.

Here's a demo of `ontrack` (use [https fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/vzmuc3gd/) in Chrome):

```js
var pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(), pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection();

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
  .then(stream => pc1.addStream(video1.srcObject = stream))
  .catch(log);

var add = (pc, can) => can && pc.addIceCandidate(can).catch(log);
pc1.onicecandidate = e => add(pc2, e.candidate);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => add(pc1, e.candidate);

pc2.ontrack = e => video2.srcObject = e.streams[0];
pc1.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => log(pc1.iceConnectionState);
pc1.onnegotiationneeded = e =>
  pc1.createOffer().then(d => pc1.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc1.localDescription))
  .then(() => pc2.createAnswer()).then(d => pc2.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription))
  .catch(log);

var log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<br>" + msg;
```

```html
<video id="video1" height="120" width="160" autoplay muted></video>
<video id="video2" height="120" width="160" autoplay></video><br>
<div id="div"></div>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: if you want to do a video conference as I fix ?